# Rails validate_uniqueness_of with delegate property

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

Trying to scope :name to a property on View's parent :form

```
class View < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :form
  delegate :facility_id, to: :form
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: :facility_id
  attr_accessible :name
```

Why doesn't it look for facility_id on form?

It instead looks for it on View

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column views.facility_id does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this used to work some time ago, chances are it still works:

`validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: { :form => :facility_id }`

Comment: Got TypeError {:form => :facility_id} is not a symbol.